# Open, Save then Close xls file in C# as part of an SSIS Scripted Task

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, etl, script-task

I have an SSIS package that pulls data from auto-generated xls files. the Microsoft Jet Engine 4 Driver will only recognise the xls documents once they've been opened and saved so I need to add a C# scripted task to automate this step.

I know nothing of C# but have tried various excerpts of code from others, unfortunately I cannot get any of them to work. There doesn't seem to be a complete excerpt of code to use and as my knowledge of C# is 0 I keep running in to a multitude of errors.

```cs
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

var ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
ExcelApp.Visible = true;
workbook.Save();
workbook.Close();
ExcelApp.Quit();
```

I used the code above but I don't think it is a complete set of code for a C# scripted task.

### EDIT

It has been mentioned that the Jet driver should work if the xls file is not another format with xls on the end. Unfortunately it doesn't work and the solution at present is to automate an open, save and close in c# as I know it works when done manually.

If anyone can help with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Excel *destination* doesn't require a file to exist in advance, so there's no reason to automate the file's creation. It would be impossible to export Excel files otherwise. `xls` is an obsolete format anyway, replaced by `xlsx` back in 2006. Online services like Google Sheets or Microsoft Online don't support `xls` for years now.

Comment: `the Microsoft Jet Engine 4 Driver will only recognise the xls documents once they've been opened and saved ` no, that's definitely not the case and never was. The only way this can happen is if the files are *fake* - `csv` or HTML files with a fake `.xls` extension. That's a hack used by many sites or applications

Comment: The *real* fix depends on what the files *really* are. For CSVs, the solution is to read them with a Flat File Source. If they are HTML files, it's probably better to get the appliation that produces the HTML file to export a CSV instead, or produce *real* Excel files.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The xls files are automatically created by an old system which still uses xls, it doesn't create xlsx files.
In my case, SSIS won't recognise the files as xls until I open them save and close. If it is as you say and they're fake xls files I should be able to open as CSV or HTML, in both instances it fails to display correctly. They system unfortunately doesn't export to CSV, only xls and HTML.

Comment: Did you try to inspect those files? Did you open them in a text editor? `fails to display correctly.` what does that mean? What happens when you try to use an Excel connection that points to those files?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I changed the extension of the file to HTML then CSV. HTML displayed some of the data but also a lot of unrecognised symbols. Excel detected the incorrect extension of CSV and converted it to xls on opening.
Is there a way of finding out what sort of file it is?
When I use an Excel connection that points to those files, I get the error 
"Test connection failed because of an error in initialising provider. External table is not in the expected format."
Thanks

Comment: Just open the file with a text editor

Comment: I open it in Word and get the File Conversion prompt. In the preview it mentions Java Excel API v2.6.10

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/ for do excel related things

```
using OfficeOpenXml;

using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(filePath))
{
    ExcelWorkbook excelWorkBook = excelPackage.Workbook;
    ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet = excelWorkBook.Worksheets.First();
    excelWorksheet.Select(excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 1].Address);

     //Save your file
    excelPackage.Save();
}
```

Comment: EPPlus won't read fake files. SSIS doesn't need any kind of automation to read real Excel files

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not sure whats happening with ssis with excel. But he asked open and save excel file right? His solution is open and save apart from correct solution?? or am I understood problem wrongly?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with SSIS and Excel. The OP says that SSIS won't recognize Excel files unless they are opened in Excel first, which is simply wrong. The question makes little sense the way it is **unless** the files are fakes.

Comment: The real solution is to find out what those files are: CSVs, HTML tables, something else? With CSVs, the easy fix is to use a Flat File Source